# Are there any Javascript CSPRNGs?

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

I'm writing some software that requires the use of a CSPRNG with javascript for use in the browser and I'm wondering what libraries are available. Crypto-js doesn't seem to have a CSPRNG I can directly call (unless I missed it?). I've looked through the Stanford crypto js library, but I'm uncertain how much analysis this code has gotten. http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.random.html

They appear to be implementing Schneier's Fortuna: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fortunaprng/

I've also seen https://www.clipperz.com/open_source/javascript_crypto_library/.

My question is there a well vetted crypto js library that has a well designed CSPRNG that generates values independently of some browser support? Or with a standard all modern browsers implement? And where is the entropy source? I'm used to crypto with languages like java and C++, not this fragmented world.

Comment: Your question is not clear: you say you want a CSPRNG, and then you talk about an entropy source. Do you need a CSRNG (unpredictable, i.e. at least seeded with a sufficient entropy source), or a CSPRNG (i.e. deterministic, but predictable only by knowing the secret seed)?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid doing any cryptography using javascript… but that's just my personal opinion.

Anyway, if you really want to walk the Javascript path, you could skip the libraries and take a look at the [`window.crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.crypto.getRandomValues) function, as long as you can live with the fact that it's an experimental API and not yet supported in all browsers… it should work on current versions of Firefox and Chrome though.

And for Opera, there's [`Math.Random()`](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto/2013Jan/0063.html) which has been implemented as a CSRNG. But you should be aware that *Math.Random* will only be a CSRNG in Opera (only in Opera, not any other browser!!!), and that the function will only return 53 bits of entropy on each call.

Besides that, I don't know of any further CSRNGs being available in Javascript, or in Javascript libraries.

**EDIT**

Some stuff that might help you find solutions to your quest:

- "[Symmetric Cryptography in Javascript - Stanford Crypto Group](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/acsac.pdf)" mentions (among other things) entropy-collection for crypto-purposes,
- and some sites out there (like https://www.grc.com/r&d/js.htm ) practically show entropy-collection for crypto-purposes using somewhat similar solutions as mentioned in the above paper.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79882/discussion-on-answer-by-e-sushi-are-there-any-javascript-csprngs).